# Regular Expression for asp.net for International & local phone numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using following regular expression to cover international phone numbers & some local phone number which can be in this format only

International Phone number

```
+123 456789123
+123456789123

+12 3456789123
+123456789123
```

Local Phone number format (Mobile no. followed by landlines numbers)

```
1234567890      
123 4567890

123123456
12 3123456
```

Regular expression which i am using

```
^[\+]{0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7,11}$
```

This regular expression works well with international numbers only irrespective of prefix `+`  is added or not but doesn't allow any while space character.

I want it to support above formats for as show in example and should also support all international phone numbers

I am working on asp.net just in case if some one wants to know.

**UPDATE:**

I finally end up using following Regex which also handles extension

```
^([\+]?[0-9]{1,3}[\s.-][0-9]{1,12})([\s.-]?[0-9]{1,4}?)$
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi some comment about you're regex

```
[\+]{0,1} could be \+?  // easier to read, + as optional
[1-9]{1} could be writen as [1-9]
[0-9]{7,11} should be [0-9\s.-]{7,11}  // phone numbers van contain - or .
```

You totaly regex would be

```
^\+?[1-9][0-9\s.-]{7,11}$
```

phone numbers could be writen as

- 070-3233123
- 070.3233123

---

**SECOND ATTEMPT**

You could break youre problems in 2 steps:

First match possibele phone number by increasing range from 11 to 20

`^\+?[1-9][0-9\s.-]{7,20}$`

next step is to remove non numbers and verify length is between 8 and 12

```
string phone = "070.3233123";

string onlyNumbers= new String(phone.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());

if (onlyNumbers.length > 8 &&  onlyNumbers.length < 12)
{
    // we got a winner
}
```

Comment: +1 for clean reply, i tried It is not working for `+123-456789123`, `+123 456789123`

Comment: yep good point you want 7 till 11 numbers and in between the whitespaces . or - of ( ) chars witch does not count as 7 till 11 numbers... let me think about it

Comment: this also matches `+1___________3`? Is that not exact? (Note: I had to use the `underscore` replacing for the `space`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^[\+]?[1-9]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{6,11}$
```

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker updated, that's because the `{3}` (fixed length) should be `{1,3}` (variable length).

Answer (score 0):

Below pattern will validate the following format

```
^\s*\+?[0-9]\d?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$
```

**Results**

```
+1 (281) 388 0388
+65 281 388-0388
+91 281 388 0388
+65 2813880388
+652813880388
+65(281)3880388
+65281388-0388
+1281388-0388
```